Issue with Dapper : random connection timeout expired
I have the following issue in an ASP.NET Core app. With Dapper I connect to a SQL Server database and I randomly have this issue:

MoveNext : SqlException Message : Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=21110; handshake=3;

I have other components connected to the database and they are not having this issue.
I have tried different troubleshoot solutions but nothing helps. If any one have any Idea, it will help.

"Is Dapper using Windows Authentication?" - I guess the real question is "does the connection string specify windows authentication", which will then be used by SqlClient; Dapper is purely an observer to this fault :)

There are a few things that can be checked: Is the authentication configuration in this component the same as the other components, and the permissions are set correctly? Check if there are a large number of concurrent connections that are causing the connection pool to be exhausted, and check that the database connection is properly released.

It seems related to a network issue. The DB Server has 2 IP adresses which made this confusion. Thank you for your help
